# Example of a weakly separable normed space that is not norm separable

Tags: normed-spaces, duality-theorems

I am looking for an example of a normed space which is separable with respect to the topology induced by all continuous linear functionals, but not separable with respect to the norm topology.

Comment: My first guess for a place to look would be $L^\infty([0,1])$; have you tried seeing if that works?

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure that a simple variation of the standard argument that $\ell^1$ is not the dual of $\ell^\infty$ shows that $\ell^\infty$ will not work. I didn't consider other $\infty$-spaces after that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that does not exist. Indeed, if

> $X$ is a normed space, then $X$ is weak separable if and only if $X$ is norm separable.

Proof.

"$\Leftarrow$": Let $X$ be norm separable. Let $A$ be countable and norm dense in $X$. Then, we use the fact that the weak topology is indeed weaker than the norm topology to see that $\overline{A}^w\supset \overline{A}^{\|\cdot\|} = X$.

"$\Rightarrow$": Now, let $A$ be countable and weakly dense in $X$. Then, clearly we have that $C:={\text{span}} ( A)$ is weakly dense in $X$ and convex. Moreover, due to [Mazur's theorem](https://books.google.de/books?id=WRc3ciSmsMMC&pg=PA122&lpg=PA122&dq=mazur%27s%20theorem%20convex%20analysis&source=bl&ots=6sCyNKUGQr&sig=JtEu3hBkMnLwDMOSsZu3xYItGV8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LJqRVa73D6ffywPN16foCA&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=mazur's%20theorem%20convex%20analysis&f=false) we have that $ \overline{C}^{\|\cdot\|}= \overline{C}^{w} =X$. Now, the rational span of $A$ will be a countable and dense set in the norm topology as $\overline {\text{span}_\mathbb{Q}} A = \overline{\text{span}} A$ in any LCS as addition and multiplication are continuous.

Comment: Why is the rational span convex?

Comment: @Ian: You are right, I fix the argument.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I think David's answer below fixes the problem by pointing out that the span with rational coefficients is norm dense in the full span, which is then convex and weakly dense.

Comment: Yeah, I fixed my answer a bit. I was too quick when I wrote it down.

Answer (score 3):

If $X$ is a Banach space then a subspace is norm-closed if and only if it is weakly closed. (This is a major difference between weak and weak*). Say $S$ is a weakly dense countable set. Let $V$ be the norm-closed span of $S$. Then $V$ is weakly closed, hence $V=X$. So the linear combinations of elements of $S$ with rational coefficients are dense in $X$, hence $X$ is norm-separable.

Comment: Interesting proof; does the first result have a name?

Comment: Ah, perfect, thank you. @Ian It is a classical theorem that norm closure and weak closure coincides for convex sets in locally convex spaces. Check out Mazur's lemma.