# Can we classify weakly compact subsets of $l^{\infty}$?

Tags: banach-spaces, weak-convergence, weak-topology

My question is as stated. The motivation behind this is that I want to prove that such subsets are norm-separable.

Comment: Do you mean weakly or weak-$\ast $-ly?

Comment: @PhoemueX, such a statement would certainly be false for the weak*-topology as the closed unit ball of $\ell_\infty$ is weak*-compact by the Banach-Alaoglu theorem and plainly inseparable.

Comment: Sorry I was reading this on my mobile and could not distinguish $I$ from $l$. I should have read the tags anyway.

Comment: @TomekKania: That was essentially why I asked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: my previous answer was plain wrong as the set $B_K$ need not be a ball of any space (for example, take the unit vector basis of $c_0$; $c_0$ does not contain any infinite-dimensional reflexive subspaces). Here is an easier argument.

Suppose that $K\subset \ell_\infty$ is weakly compact. As $\ell_\infty$ is isometric to the dual space of $\ell_1$, it carries the weak* topology, which is coarser than the weak topology of $\ell_\infty$. In particular, $K$ is also compact in the weak* topology and the two relative topologies agree on $K$. However, as $\ell_1$ is separable, weak* compact subsets of $\ell_\infty$ are second-countable. One may use Mazur's lemma (as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1343666/17929)) to conclude that a set is weakly separable if and only if it is norm-separable.

<strike>Suppose that $K\subset \ell_\infty$ is weakly compact. Then, by [Mazur's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%27s_lemma), so is the closed convex hull of $K\cup \{0\}$, call it $B_K$. Consider $\ell_\infty$ as the dual space to $\ell_1$. Since the weak* topology on $\ell_\infty$ is coarser than the weak topology, by compactness, they must be equal on $B_K$. [Since $B_K$ is weakly compact, $X_K$ is reflexive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199478/equivalence-of-reflexive-and-weakly-compact). However, the weak*-topology and the weak topologies of $\ell_\infty$ coincide on $X_K$, so $X_K$ is weak*-closed. Then, by reflexivity, $X^*_K$ is isomorphic to $\ell_1 / (X_K)_\perp$, where $(X_K)_\perp$ is the [pre-annihilator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1529891/representation-of-weak-cont-linear-functional-on-a-subspace-which-is-not-weak/1530694#1530694) of $X_K$ so $X_K$ (and hence $K$ itself) is norm-separable.</strike>

This can be generalised as follows. If $\Gamma$ is infinite, then each weakly compact subset of $\ell_\infty(\Gamma)$ has density at most $|\Gamma|$. (For example, for regular cardinals, it follows from Theorem 2.6 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.05239.pdf).)

Comment: I have a (not really related) question: You seem to know quite a lot about Banach spaces and their geometry. I only know the most basic things (essentially what is in Rudin's book plus reflexivity and uniform convexity). What would you recommend (preferably a book) to read, starting from this position?

Comment: @PhoemueX, I would recommend Albiac and Kalton's *Topics in Banach space theory*, it is a great book!

Comment: I can see the argument but I am not quite sure about the step with $B_K$ the closed ball of its linear span.

Comment: What I don't understand is why $B_K$ is the unit ball of $X_K$? There are no assumptions on the norm values of $K$ or that it's convex hull contains the origin.

Comment: To apply the theorem with the unit ball being weakly compact characterising reflexivity don't we need $B_K$ to be those elements of $X_K$ of norm at most 1?

Comment: Ah I see! That's a nice generalisation too, I hadn't thought of that!

Comment: I seem to be missing something, but how does Mazur's lemma imply the weak compactness of $B_K$? The general case (Krein-Šmulian theorem) seems to require quite a sophisticated argument, which I'm looking to avoid.

Comment: Well, Mazur's lemma is needed on the way. Please see here: https://books.google.cz/books?id=fD-GeCsqoqkC&pg=PA254&lpg=PA254&dq=convex+hull+of+weakly+compact&source=bl&ots=qv270cdTpu&sig=CAhKXMcZomq0_-H1ksT7y0p1vDo&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDj97DuIvWAhUHVBQKHaHICOUQ6AEIRDAD#v=onepage&q=convex%20hull%20of%20weakly%20compact&f=false

Answer (score 3):

Another way to prove this is to use the following result:

> **Lemma**: If $K \subset \ell_{\infty}$ is weakly compact, then it is weakly metrisable.
>
> *Proof*: For $x,y \in K$ we set,
>
> $$ d(x,y) = 2^{-n} |x_n-y_n|. $$
>
> Since $K$ is norm bounded (by the uniform boundedness principle) the sum is finite and we can readily check this defines a metric on $K.$ Moreover it is a locally convex space defined by the coordinate maps $x \mapsto x_n.$
>
> Since $(K,d)$ is generated by fewer functionals compared to the weak topology, it is coarser and so the identity map,
>
> $$ (K,w) \rightarrow (K,d) $$
>
> is continuous. Since $(K,w)$ is compact and $(K,d)$ is Hausdorff the map is a homeomorphism, so the topologies coincide.

Hence it follows that $K$ is weakly separable, by using total boundedness and taking $\frac1n$-nets.

Now let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a weakly dense subset of $K$ and set,

$$ C = \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n t_i x_{k_i} \mid n \in \mathbb N, t_1, \dots, t_n \in [0,1] \cap \mathbb Q, \sum_{i=1}^n t_i = 1, k_1 < \dots < k_n \right\}. $$

That is, the rational convex hull of the $x_n$'s. One can easily show this is weakly dense in $\mathrm{conv}\ K,$ so by Mazur's lemma,

$$ \overline{\mathrm{conv}}^{\lVert\cdot\rVert} C = \overline{\mathrm{conv}}^w C = \overline{\mathrm{conv}}\ K. $$

Since $C$ is countable, $\overline{\mathrm{conv}}\ K$ and hence $K$ is norm separable.